# Shell script does not exit to the prompt

Tags: linux, bash, shell, exit

I have a shell script `ws_appl_process` that stop/start WebSphere servers:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ------------------------------------
# WebSphere Application Server process
# ------------------------------------
# PLEASE NOTE: This script assumes no spaces in the server names
# Finally, alter $APPSERVERS if server1 is required to start

PROF_HOME="/opt/WebSphere/AppServer855/profiles/xxxxxx"

## set colors
ec=`tput setaf 1`       # error color
rc=`tput sgr 0`         # reset color to default

if [ ! -d $PROF_HOME ];then
   echo " "
   echo "${ec}WARNING:${rc} unable to locate directory $PROF_HOME! No action taken."
   echo " "
else
   . $PROF_HOME/bin/setupCmdLine.sh
   SERVERDIR=$PROF_HOME/config/cells/$WAS_CELL/nodes/$WAS_NODE/servers
   APPSERVERS=`ls $SERVERDIR | egrep -v "jmsserver|nodeagent|web$"`
   case "$1" in
   'start')
       # delay start by 30 seconds to let OS 'calm down' on startup
       sleep 30

       # start jmmserver first, if applicable
       if [ -f $SERVERDIR/jmsserver/server.xml ]; then
           $PROF_HOME/bin/startServer.sh jmsserver
       fi

       # start all servers found in config directory
       for i in $APPSERVERS;do
           $PROF_HOME/bin/startServer.sh $i &
           sleep 1
       done
       ;;
   'stop')
       for i in $APPSERVERS;do
           $PROF_HOME/bin/stopServer.sh $i &
       done

       if [ -f $SERVERDIR/jmsserver/server.xml ]; then
           $PROF_HOME/bin/stopServer.sh jmsserver
       fi
       ;;
   *)
       echo "Usage: $0 { start | stop }"
       exit 1
   esac
fi
exit $?
```

Running this script

```
./ws_appl_process stop
```

will do what is intended, e.g. stop or start.

However, the script does NOT return to the prompt e.g. `user@server:~>`.

I have to manually hit the `<RETURN>` or `<ENTER>` key to get to the prompt.
I have tried to modify the last command

```
exit $?
```

to

```
exit 0
```

or

```
exit $?
exit 0
```

with no luck.

I need the script to return automatically to the prompt. The reason is that I am automating the monitor of the servers, and eventually bring them back, i.e.

`./ws_appl_process start`

**The OS:**
Linux xxxxxx 3.0.101-108.101-default #1 SMP Tue Aug 13 08:31:17 UTC 2019 (d0a7b7a) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**The shell:**
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(2)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

How can I force the script back to the prompt?

Appreciate any comments.

Comment: Your script returns and the shell displays a new prompt, but then one of the background jobs produces some output. Hitting enter simply executes a null command and forces the shell to draw *another* prompt.

Comment: In other words, just because you don't *see* the prompt doesn't mean the shell isn't ready and waiting for more input.

Comment: @chepner thank you for the comments. I understood that. What I am doing is use `EXPECT` scripts to call the scripts/commands. The `EXPECT` script `expect` a return from a `send`. If the script does not return to the prompt, no way I can proceed to the next ...

Comment: Redirect the output of the background processes to a file or `/dev/null` so they don't interfere with the shell prompt.

Comment: I can't find out what background process is holding the thread.